# Sqlite backupDatabase with callback

Tags: vb.net, callback, backup, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to use callback with sqlite backupdatabase , and it doesn't seem to work.

Below is the code I use. The callback is fired aprox. 1/s but the destination file is not getting any bigger, and the debug output is unchanged. remainingpages value doesn't change. The backup without callback works OK.

Output:

Pages: 10000 remaining: 79091 TotalPages: 89091

Pages: 10000 remaining: 79091 TotalPages: 89091

```
Private Function DBcallback(source As SQLiteConnection, sourceName As String, destination As SQLiteConnection, destinationName As String, pages As Integer, remainingPages As Integer, totalPages As Integer, retry As Boolean) As Boolean
    Debug.WriteLine("Pages: " & pages & " remaining: " & remainingPages & " TotalPages: " & totalPages)
    Return True
End Function

Public Function BackupDataBase(ByVal backupDestination As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Using connection = New SQLiteConnection(StrConnection)
            Using destination = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source= " & backupDestination & "; Version=3;")

                connection.Open()
                destination.Open()
                connection.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", 10000, AddressOf DBcallback, 0)

                Return True
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Return False
End Function
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious question, are you sure that BackupDataBase is actually getting called?

Comment: Well the DBcallback function is firing, and also backup file is created, just its size is 0 bytes all the time. If I stop debugging the file size is changed but the backup is not whole.